# Java web start can't run my JAR file

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, japplet

I have the following jnlp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://etrdwebs01/RSA/folder1/folder2/">
<information>
    <title>Jnlp Testing</title>
    <vendor>My Company</vendor>
    <description>Testing JNLP</description>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <java version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="MyJAR.jar"/>
</resources>
<applet-desc name="TEST_JAR" main-class="MYJAR.MainApplet" documentbase="http://etrdwebs01/RSA/folder1/folder2/" width="400" height="400">
</applet-desc>
```

The problem as the following:

- When the code base set to the mentioned value, I got classNotFoundException on the main class which resides in the MYJAR package with the name MainApplet.
- If I change the codebase to ".", I got the permission denied exception as the following:

> basic: exception: Permission denied: file:/C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/Content.IE5/2FTY5X2G/.
>   ExitException[ 3]java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied: file:/C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/Content.IE5/2FTY5X2G/
>       at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Ignored exception: ExitException[ 3]java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied: file:/C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/Content.IE5/2FTY5X2G/
>   cache: Clean up the reference queue: file:/C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/Content.IE5/2FTY5X2G/MYJAR.jarjnlp
>   cache: deregisterReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@9c2651c6: 3
>   cache: Clean up the reference queue: file:/C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/Content.IE5/2FTY5X2G/MYJAR.jarjnlp
>   cache: deregisterReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@9c2651c6: 2

How can I solve this issue????

Comment: Did it work on example project(.jar) ???

Comment: I'm seeing 'file not found' on the Jar (trying URL http://etrdwebs01/RSA/folder1/folder2/MyJAR.jar).

Comment: Sorry SkorpEN, I didn't get your point, would you please explain more?

Comment: Andrew, Did you mean that I need to use the full path in the href attribute of the Jar tag.